# Shorten a string to maximum N characters and only include full words - R

Tags: r

I'm trying to shorten a string so that it is at most 50 characters long. However, only complete words should be included.

Example:

```
a <- "This is a very long string that should be a maximum of 50 characters and just full words"
```

expected result:

```
"This is a very long string that should be a"
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: This may help strsplit(a,' ')

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strwrap` from *base*:

```
strwrap(a, 50)[1]
#[1] "This is a very long string that should be a"
```

or using `stringi::stri_wrap`:

```
stringi::stri_wrap(a, 50)[1]
#[1] "This is a very long string that should be a"
```

or using `sub`:

```
sub("(.{1,50})(\\s.*|$)", '\\1', a)
#[1] "This is a very long string that should be a"

sub("(.{1,50})(\\s.*|$)", '\\1', "Side by Side")
#[1] "Side by Side"
```

Comment: Hi GKi,
thanks a lot for your fast answers.
I would choose your last solution, but it doesn't work for short strings, that are shorter than 50 characters. 
sub("(.{1,50})\\s.*", '\\1', "Side by Side") ---> "Side by"
How to fix that?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot that condition. See update.